# Updated Miktex on Windows 7 and eps figures no longer appear using xelatex

Tags: xetex, eps

I recently (April) updated MiKTeX on my Windows 7 machine and when I compile
code that used to work using `xelatex`, my eps files no longer appear - only
a space where they should go along with the caption.

Here is a small version where the figure does not show up using xelatex:

```
\documentclass[10 pt]{book}

\usepackage{standalone} \standalonetrue
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htbp] % float placement: (h)ere, page (t)op, page (b)ottom, other (p)age
  \centering
  \includegraphics[bb=40 137 566 655,height=1.1in,keepaspectratio]{squarebdd.eps}
  \caption{Square $ABCD$}
  \label{fig:squarebdd}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I am including the log file:

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99992 (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit) (preloaded format=xelatex 2016.4.20)  23 APR 2016 10:19
entering extended mode
**./test.tex
(test.tex
LaTeX2e <2016/03/31>
Babel <3.9q> and hyphenation patterns for 70 language(s) loaded.
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\book.cls"
Document Class: book 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\bk10.clo"
 File: bk10.clo 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count79
\c@chapter=\count80
\c@section=\count81
\c@subsection=\count82
\c@subsubsection=\count83
\c@paragraph=\count84
\c@subparagraph=\count85
\c@figure=\count86
\c@table=\count87
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\standalone\standalone.sty"
Package: standalone 2015/07/15 v1.2 Package to include TeX sub-files with pream
bles

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifluatex.sty"
Package: ifluatex 2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
Package ifluatex Info: LuaTeX not detected.
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifpdf.sty"
Package: ifpdf 2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
Package ifpdf Info: pdfTeX in PDF mode is not detected.
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\ifxetex\ifxetex.sty"
Package: ifxetex 2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\xkeyval\xkeyval.sty"
Package: xkeyval 2014/12/03 v2.7a package option processing (HA)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\xkeyval\xkeyval.tex"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\xkeyval\xkvutils.tex"
\XKV@toks=\toks14
\XKV@tempa@toks=\toks15

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\xkeyval\keyval.tex"))
\XKV@depth=\count88
File: xkeyval.tex 2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\currfile\currfile.sty"
Package: currfile 2013/02/01 v0.7b Provides the file path elements of the curre
nt input file

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\oberdiek\kvoptions.sty"
Package: kvoptions 2011/06/30 v3.11 Key value format for package options (HO)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ltxcmds.sty"
Package: ltxcmds 2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\kvsetkeys.sty"
Package: kvsetkeys 2012/04/25 v1.16 Key value parser (HO)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\infwarerr.sty"
Package: infwarerr 2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\etexcmds.sty"
Package: etexcmds 2011/02/16 v1.5 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
Package etexcmds Info: Could not find \expanded.
(etexcmds)             That can mean that you are not using pdfTeX 1.50 or
(etexcmds)             that some package has redefined \expanded.
(etexcmds)             In the latter case, load this package earlier.
)))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\filehook\filehook.sty"
Package: filehook 2011/10/12 v0.5d Hooks for input files
)
\c@currfiledepth=\count89
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\gincltex\gincltex.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\svn-prov\svn-prov.sty"
Package: svn-prov 2010/04/24 v3.1862 Package Date/Version from SVN Keywords
)
Package: gincltex 2011/09/04 v0.3 Include external LaTeX files like graphics

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\adjustbox\adjustbox.sty"
Package: adjustbox 2012/05/21 v1.0 Adjusting TeX boxes (trim, clip, ...)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\adjustbox\adjcalc.sty"
Package: adjcalc 2012/05/16 v1.1 Provides advanced setlength with multiple back
-ends (calc, etex, pgfmath)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\adjustbox\trimclip.sty"
Package: trimclip 2012/05/16 v1.0 Trim and clip general TeX material

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\graphicx.sty"
Package: graphicx 2014/10/28 v1.0g Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\graphics.sty"
Package: graphics 2016/01/03 v1.0q Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\trig.sty"
Package: trig 2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\00miktex\graphics.cfg"
File: graphics.cfg 2016/01/02 v1.10 sample graphics configuration
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: xetex.def on input line 95.

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\xelatex\xetex-def\xetex.def"
File: xetex.def 2016/04/06 v4.08 LaTeX color/graphics driver for XeTeX (TeX Liv
e/RRM/JK)
))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen103
\Gin@req@width=\dimen104
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\collectbox\collectbox.sty"
Package: collectbox 2012/05/17 v0.4b Collect macro arguments as boxes
\collectedbox=\box26
)
\tc@llx=\dimen105
\tc@lly=\dimen106
\tc@urx=\dimen107
\tc@ury=\dimen108
Package trimclip Info: Using driver 'tc-xetex.def'.

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\adjustbox\tc-xetex.def"
File: tc-xetex.def 2012/05/13 v1.0 Clipping driver for xetex
))
\adjbox@Width=\dimen109
\adjbox@Height=\dimen110
\adjbox@Depth=\dimen111
\adjbox@Totalheight=\dimen112

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\ifoddpage\ifoddpage.sty"
Package: ifoddpage 2011/09/13 v1.0 Conditionals for odd/even page detection
\c@checkoddpage=\count90
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\ltxmisc\varwidth.sty"
Package: varwidth 2009/03/30 ver 0.92;  Variable-width minipages
\@vwid@box=\box27
\sift@deathcycles=\count91
\@vwid@loff=\dimen113
\@vwid@roff=\dimen114
))
\gincltex@box=\box28
))
No file test.aux.
\openout1 = `test.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
File: squarebdd.eps Graphic file (type eps)
<squarebdd.eps>
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <7> on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <5> on input line 13.
Requested font "cmsl10" at 10.0pt
 [1

] (test.aux)

LaTeX Warning: Label(s) may have changed. Rerun to get cross-references right.

 ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:


Output written on test.pdf (1 page).
```

When I compile the original code I included with pdflatex, the picture runs
over the caption.

Update (4/24/16):  Ok, three things:

1. When I removed bb, the figure does appear correctly if I use pdflatex.
2. This is not a solution for me.  I have a co-author who needs to use xelatex and eps figures (not converted pdf figures).  They are running an updated version of Miktex on a Windows 10 machine and everything works well.  I cannot, therefore, be changing my code and running pdflatex instead.
3. I tried replacing xetex.def with older versions in the directory:
   C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\xelatex\xetex-def
   (One from 9/11/2015 and one from 5/2/2014).  Neither helped.

Ok, I am including a link to the squarebdd.eps file that gave me the original
problem.

[https://www.dropbox.com/s/cm46vd7olp1yghe/squarebdd.eps?dl=0][3]

Here is what is in my dvipdfmx.cfg file (dated 4/24/2014):

```
D  "rungs -q -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dEPSCrop -sDEVICE=pdfwrite      -dCompatibilityLevel=%v -dAutoFilterGrayImages=false -dGrayImageFilter=/FlateEncode -dAutoFilterColorImages=false -dColorImageFilter=/FlateEncode -sOutputFile='%o' '%i' -c quit"

% pre-2013 invocation using -sPAPERSIZE instead of -dEPSCrop, no other   changes:
%D  "rungs -q -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sPAPERSIZE=a0 -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=%v -dAutoFilterGrayImages=false -dGrayImageFilter=/FlateEncode -dAutoFilterColorImages=false -dColorImageFilter=/FlateEncode -sOutputFile='%o' '%i' -c quit"

% other random ps converters people have experimented with.
%D "/usr/local/bin/ps2pdf -dEPSCrop '%i' '%o'"
%D "/usr/texbin/epstopdf '%i' -o '%o'"
%D "/usr/bin/pstopdf '%i' -o '%o'"
```

Update 5/1/2015:  I've uninstalled and reinstalled Miktex once more
and am no longer using a beta version.  I tried my test examples using squarebdd.eps and included the .eps extension.  It still does not show up!

Here is the log file:

```
 This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99992 (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit)    (preloaded format=xelatex 2016.4.30)  1 MAY 2016 10:09
entering extended mode
**./test.tex
(test.tex
LaTeX2e <2015/10/01> patch level 2
Babel <3.9n> and hyphenation patterns for 69 languages loaded.
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\book.cls"
Document Class: book 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\bk10.clo"
File: bk10.clo 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count79
\c@chapter=\count80
\c@section=\count81
\c@subsection=\count82
\c@subsubsection=\count83
\c@paragraph=\count84
\c@subparagraph=\count85
\c@figure=\count86
\c@table=\count87
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\standalone\standalone.sty"
Package: standalone 2015/07/15 v1.2 Package to include TeX sub-files with pream
bles

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifluatex.sty"
Package: ifluatex 2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
Package ifluatex Info: LuaTeX not detected.
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifpdf.sty"
Package: ifpdf 2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
Package ifpdf Info: pdfTeX in PDF mode is not detected.
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\ifxetex\ifxetex.sty"
Package: ifxetex 2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\xkeyval\xkeyval.sty"
Package: xkeyval 2014/12/03 v2.7a package option processing (HA)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\xkeyval\xkeyval.tex"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\xkeyval\xkvutils.tex"
\XKV@toks=\toks14
\XKV@tempa@toks=\toks15

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\xkeyval\keyval.tex"))
\XKV@depth=\count88
File: xkeyval.tex 2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\currfile\currfile.sty"
Package: currfile 2015/04/23 v0.7c Provides the file path elements of the  curre
nt input file

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\oberdiek\kvoptions.sty"
Package: kvoptions 2011/06/30 v3.11 Key value format for package options (HO)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ltxcmds.sty"
Package: ltxcmds 2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\kvsetkeys.sty"
Package: kvsetkeys 2012/04/25 v1.16 Key value parser (HO)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\infwarerr.sty"
Package: infwarerr 2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\etexcmds.sty"
Package: etexcmds 2011/02/16 v1.5 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands  (HO)
Package etexcmds Info: Could not find \expanded.
(etexcmds)             That can mean that you are not using pdfTeX 1.50 or
(etexcmds)             that some package has redefined \expanded.
(etexcmds)             In the latter case, load this package earlier.
)))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\filehook\filehook.sty"
Package: filehook 2011/10/12 v0.5d Hooks for input files
)
\c@currfiledepth=\count89
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\gincltex\gincltex.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\svn-prov\svn-prov.sty"
Package: svn-prov 2010/04/24 v3.1862 Package Date/Version from SVN Keywords
)
Package: gincltex 2011/09/04 v0.3 Include external LaTeX files like graphics

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\adjustbox\adjustbox.sty"
Package: adjustbox 2012/05/21 v1.0 Adjusting TeX boxes (trim, clip, ...)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\adjustbox\adjcalc.sty"
Package: adjcalc 2012/05/16 v1.1 Provides advanced setlength with multiple back
-ends (calc, etex, pgfmath)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\adjustbox\trimclip.sty"
Package: trimclip 2012/05/16 v1.0 Trim and clip general TeX material

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\graphicx.sty"
Package: graphicx 2014/10/28 v1.0g Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\graphics.sty"
Package: graphics 2016/01/03 v1.0q Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\trig.sty"
Package: trig 2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\00miktex\graphics.cfg"
File: graphics.cfg 2016/01/02 v1.10 sample graphics configuration
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: xetex.def on input line 95.

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\xelatex\xetex-def\xetex.def"
File: xetex.def 2016/04/06 v4.08 LaTeX color/graphics driver for XeTeX (TeX Liv
e/RRM/JK)
))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen103
\Gin@req@width=\dimen104
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\collectbox\collectbox.sty"
Package: collectbox 2012/05/17 v0.4b Collect macro arguments as boxes
\collectedbox=\box26
)
\tc@llx=\dimen105
\tc@lly=\dimen106
\tc@urx=\dimen107
\tc@ury=\dimen108
Package trimclip Info: Using driver 'tc-xetex.def'.

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\adjustbox\tc-xetex.def"
File: tc-xetex.def 2012/05/13 v1.0 Clipping driver for xetex
))
\adjbox@Width=\dimen109
\adjbox@Height=\dimen110
\adjbox@Depth=\dimen111
\adjbox@Totalheight=\dimen112

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\ifoddpage\ifoddpage.sty"
Package: ifoddpage 2016/04/23 v1.1 Conditionals for odd/even page detection
\c@checkoddpage=\count90
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\ltxmisc\varwidth.sty"
Package: varwidth 2009/03/30 ver 0.92;  Variable-width minipages
\@vwid@box=\box27
\sift@deathcycles=\count91
\@vwid@loff=\dimen113
\@vwid@roff=\dimen114
))
\gincltex@box=\box28
))
No file test.aux.
\openout1 = `test.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 11.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 11.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 11.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 11.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 11.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 11.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 11.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 11.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 11.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 11.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 11.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 11.
File: example-image.eps Graphic file (type eps)
<example-image.eps>
File: squarebdd.eps Graphic file (type eps)
<squarebdd.eps>
Requested font "cmsl10" at 10.0pt
[1

] (test.aux)

*File List*
book.cls    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
bk10.clo    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
standalone.sty    2015/07/15 v1.2 Package to include TeX sub-files with   preambl
es
ifluatex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
ifpdf.sty    2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
ifxetex.sty    2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
xkeyval.sty    2014/12/03 v2.7a package option processing (HA)
xkeyval.tex    2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
currfile.sty    2015/04/23 v0.7c Provides the file path elements of the   current
input file
kvoptions.sty    2011/06/30 v3.11 Key value format for package options (HO)
ltxcmds.sty    2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2012/04/25 v1.16 Key value parser (HO)
infwarerr.sty    2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2011/02/16 v1.5 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
filehook.sty    2011/10/12 v0.5d Hooks for input files
gincltex.sty    2011/09/04 v0.3 Include external LaTeX files like graphics
svn-prov.sty    2010/04/24 v3.1862 Package Date/Version from SVN Keywords
adjustbox.sty    2012/05/21 v1.0 Adjusting TeX boxes (trim, clip, ...)
adjcalc.sty    2012/05/16 v1.1 Provides advanced setlength with multiple back-
ends (calc, etex, pgfmath)
trimclip.sty    2012/05/16 v1.0 Trim and clip general TeX material
graphicx.sty    2014/10/28 v1.0g Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
graphics.sty    2016/01/03 v1.0q Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
trig.sty    2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2016/01/02 v1.10 sample graphics configuration
xetex.def    2016/04/06 v4.08 LaTeX color/graphics driver for XeTeX (TeX Liv
e/RRM/JK)
collectbox.sty    2012/05/17 v0.4b Collect macro arguments as boxes
tc-xetex.def    2012/05/13 v1.0 Clipping driver for xetex
ifoddpage.sty    2016/04/23 v1.1 Conditionals for odd/even page detection
varwidth.sty    2009/03/30 ver 0.92;  Variable-width minipages
squarebdd.eps    Graphic file (type eps)
```

Output written on test.pdf (1 page).
Here is a picture of what I get:

[image]

Comment: I did uninstall and reinstall MikTeX after I initially had problems after updating my old installation of MikTex (originally from 2013).  I did install MWE and used example-image.eps in my code and it appears, although my eps files do not.  Any thoughts?  I generated them using GSView and had no trouble with them before the update.  When I run example-image.eps through GSView and convert it to an eps it no longer appears.

Comment: I have a colleague whose has the latest version of MIktex installed on a Windows 10 machine and the eps files show up perfectly.  How can I add an eps file?

Comment: Don't write like `bb=40 137 566 655` for eps, which should
have its own BoundingBox data. Use `trim` or `viewport` instead in
order to choose a special region of an eps image.
This is a limitation in `xetex.def`.

Comment: What would the code look like instead?  Also, can I modify xetex.def or go back to an older version?

Comment: First try,
`\includegraphics[height=1.1in]{squarebdd.eps}`.
without `bb=40 137 566 655`.
Second, read a document on graphicx package for `trim`
or `viewport`.
If the eps image is not shown in the first trial,
the eps may be problematic for Ghostscript to convert into pdf.

Comment: I removed the bb and it worked for pdflatex, but not xelatex, which I what I need to use.

Comment: I realized that in my first attempt to use example-image, I did not include the .eps extension in the name.  When I went back and did that, the file does not appear.

Comment: Can you upload the EPS somewhere we can grap it an test it on our systems?

Comment: the example-image.eps I used is part of the package MWE.  Perhaps the problem is related to the fact that my Latex Patch Level is Latex2e from 2016/03/31.

Comment: There is no problem for `example-image.eps` in the package `MWE`.
The eps image is included without any problem in xelatex
with LaTeX2e 2016/03/31 and with xetex.def 2016/04/06 v4.08.
Check that the Ghostscript option is -dEPSCrop.

Comment: Where can I check that?

Comment: It looks like I am using gs9.07.  Would that matter?

Comment: I don't know anything about MikTeX. In the case of TeX Live,
the Ghostscript option is written at the D section in the file
texmf-dist/dvipdfmx/dvipdfmx.cfg.

Comment: I changed to gs9.19 and it did not help.

Comment: I can find the file dvipdfmx.cfg, but how do you edit it?

Comment: I would be happy to upload my original squarebdd.eps to a site, but don't easily have a place to do that myself.

Comment: Ok, I've uploaded squarebdd.eps for you to look at.

Comment: Ok, I am including a link to the squarebdd.eps file that gave me the original
problem.

[https://www.dropbox.com/s/cm46vd7olp1yghe/squarebdd.eps?dl=0][3]

Comment: I found that your eps has
`%%BoundingBox: 40 137 566 655`.
They are exactly the same values as you wrote in
your source:
`bb=40 137 566 655`.
In this case, `bb=40 137 566 655` is harmless.
So your first source is fine, and the results are in
(http://members2.jcom.home.ne.jp/wt1357ak/eps-test.zip)

But I recommend not to write `bb=llx lly urx ury` in the
case of eps images.
As I said previously, one cannot choose a special region
by changing `bb=llx lly urx ury`. One must use `trim` or
`viewport`.
Anyway your XeTeX environment needs to be improved.

Comment: Yes, but why doesn't my figure show up?  How does my XeTex environment need to be improved?

Comment: I've added what is in my dvipdfmx.cfg file:

Comment: I can see `-dEPSCrop`, so it seems ok.
But I don't know MikTeX, so I don't know why
the image is not shown in your case.

Answer (score 1):

After a week of checking versions and uninstalling and reinstalling Miktex, I finally have the eps figures working in xetex.

1. I deleted all folders relating to Miktex from any and all temporary local folders.
2. I turned off my virus softward (Kaspersky)
3. I uninstalled as an administrator:  Go to C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\internal. Right-click on uninstall_admin.exe and select Execute as Administrator.
4. I installed Miktex from the website (64bit version) and did not run any updates.

Thanks for all of the suggestions/help!